# are these two fractions a record for m, n<559?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

$\dfrac 1{344}$ has a recurring decimal period which is $906976744186046511627$.

$\dfrac 1{559}$ has a recurring decimal period which is $178890876565295169946332737030411449016100$

I note that $$\gcd(178890876565295169946332737030411449016100,  906976744186046511627)=\\
  23255813953488372093,$$ which is a big number.

Does other two fractions $\frac{1}{m}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$, $m$ integers $m\neq n$ <559 exist such the gcd of their recurring decimal period is greater than $23255813953488372093$?

Comment: I found an example starting from yours (use $1/172$ instead of $1/344$), but only because you put the two zeros to the end of the period of $1/559$ instead of in the beginning. With $1/172$ you get an extra factor $25$ to the gcd, but it is factor only due to those two trailing zeros.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yet another question about [559](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567051/integers-congruent-to-344-pmod-559)!  Note that $\gcd(344,559)=43$, and that big number is the recurring decimal period for $\dfrac1{43}$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner and why?

Comment: I am curious to know why too!

Comment: I see you asked that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569010/is-there-an-explanation-for-these-recurring-decimal-expansions)

Comment: If we remove the factors $2$ and $5$ from a given positive integer $n$ , and the result is , lets say , $m$ and if $m>1$ holds , then the period length of $\frac{1}{n}$ is equal to $ord_{10}(m)$ , the smallest positive integer $k$ with $10^k\equiv 1\mod m$