# Is there an explanation for these recurring decimal expansions?

Tags: number-theory

$\dfrac {1}{344}$ has a recurring decimal period which is $906976744186046511627$

$\dfrac {1}{559}$ has a recurring decimal period which is $178890876565295169946332737030411449016100$

I note that $$\gcd(178890876565295169946332737030411449016100,  906976744186046511627)=\\
  23255813953488372093,$$

An user pointed me out that

Gcd(344,559)=43

And

$23255813953488372093$ is the decimal recurring expansion of $\frac{1}{43}$.
Why this?

Comment: Why do you repeat the same question an hour after ? This is not to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I'll label as $K_n$ the recurring portion of $n$.
We simply  have that the following is satisfied 
$$nK_n=10^t-a$$ for some $t$ where $a\leq10$

In some cases, you'll need to account for the leading terms before the recurrence starts. I leave this to you.