# Numbers of the form 1444...44456

Tags: number-theory

In my research I came across these numbers:

$1456,14456,144456,1444456...$

I suspect that when a number of this form is divisible by $344$, then it is also divisible by $559$, but I have no proof. Adding 1 to these numbers you have

$1457, 14457, 144457...$

Among them I found few primes

Comment: @Peter I found few primes of this form

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Another post involving [$559$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568967/are-these-two-fractions-a-record-for-m-n559). There are also few primes of the form $11$, $111$, $1111$, ...

Comment: @J.W. Tanner sure 559 and 344 are involved in mysterious ec primes

Comment: Are you posting under yet another new user name?  What's up?

Comment: **Hint** $\bmod 13\!:\ \color{#c00}{14\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{14}4\cdots 4\equiv \color{#c00}14\cdots 4\equiv\cdots\equiv 14\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,14\cdots456\equiv \color{#0a0}{15}6\equiv\color{#0a0}26\equiv 0$ $\ \ \ $

Comment: $f(n) = (13 \cdot 10^n + 113)/9$ is prime for $n = 2, 8, 75, 135, 2637, 5354 \ldots$.  Probably infinitely many, but there are no known proofs for this kind of conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote the following:

> I suspect that when a number of this form is divisible by $344$, then it is also divisible by $559$,
>
> but I have no proof.

Here is a proof.

These numbers are $13\times\dfrac{10^n+8}9$, so they are all divisible by $13$.

Those which are divisible by $344=8\times43$ are divisible by $43$.

Since $13$ and $43$ are relatively prime, if a number of this form is divisible by $344$,

it will be divisible by $43\times13=559$.

Comment: (+1) Nice proof.